# I need help in an if else statement in R until a certain condition is met

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to create a code that does the following:
when the value of z is greater than 2 (a threshold)  then assign the value 1 UNTIL the value of z crosses zero and when the value of z is less than -2 (a threshold) then assign the value -1 until z crosses zero else give zeros.
This is a small example but of course I don't want this result.

```
z<-c(1, 1.5, 1.3, 2.2, 2.4, 3, 2.2, 1.3, 1, 0.5, 0.2, -.03,
     -1, 0.3, -1.3, -2.3, -3, -1, 0.3, 0, 1, -1)
ifelse(z>2,1,ifelse(z<(-2),(-1),0))
# the result is:
[1]  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0
# But: I want the result like this
[1]  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0
```

another example:

```
z<-c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2.2, 2.3, 3, 3.4, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1.3, -0.5, 0.3, 
     1, -1, -2.2, -2.3, -1, 0.5, 1, -0.5, -1)
```

I want the result like this

```
[1] 0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0
```

By the way the data I use is in XTS format if it helps.
Thanks in advance

Comment: z<-c(0.5,1,1.5,2.2,2.3,3,3.4,1.5,0.5,1,1.3,-0.5,0.3,1,-1,-2.2,-2.3,-1,0.5,1,-0.5,-1)
) and expected result is [1] 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should now do what you want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
z <- c(1, 1.5, 1.3, 2.2, 2.4, 3, 2.2, 1.3, 1, 0.5, 0.2, -.03, -1, 0.3, 
       -1.3, -2.3, -3, -1, 0.3, 0,1, -1)
z <- data.frame(z) # Convert z into data.frame
z %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(z > 2 ~ 1,    # assign 1 if z > 2
                            z < -2 ~ -1,  # assign -1 if z < -2
                            z == 0 ~ 0,   # assign 0 if z == 0
                            sign(z) != sign(lag(z)) ~ 0,  # assign 0 if z switches signs
                            TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>%   # assign NA in all other cases
  fill(result, .direction = "down") %>%   # fill NA values based on the last non-NA above
  replace_na(list(result = 0)) # convert leading NA values to 0

       z result
1   1.00      0
2   1.50      0
3   1.30      0
4   2.20      1
5   2.40      1
6   3.00      1
7   2.20      1
8   1.30      1
9   1.00      1
10  0.50      1
11  0.20      1
12 -0.03      0
13 -1.00      0
14  0.30      0
15 -1.30      0
16 -2.30     -1
17 -3.00     -1
18 -1.00     -1
19  0.30      0
20  0.00      0
21  1.00      0
22 -1.00      0
```

The result column matches your desired output for the first example of `z`.

Here is the result from your second example of `z`.

```
      z result
1   0.5      0
2   1.0      0
3   1.5      0
4   2.2      1
5   2.3      1
6   3.0      1
7   3.4      1
8   1.5      1
9   0.5      1
10  1.0      1
11  1.3      1
12 -0.5      0
13  0.3      0
14  1.0      0
15 -1.0      0
16 -2.2     -1
17 -2.3     -1
18 -1.0     -1
19  0.5      0
20  1.0      0
21 -0.5      0
22 -1.0      0
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what I want is different as i said, i want to have a value of 1 for example only if z is greater than 2 and keep giving 1's until z crosses zero (and same for -ve values. for example z<-c(0.5,1,1.5,2.2,2.3,3,3.4,1.5,0.5,1,1.3,-0.5,0.3,1,-1,-2.2,-2.3,-1,0.5,1,-0.5,-1)
this is the result i want [1] 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0

Comment: @hishamsaad - I updated my answer now that I have a clearer understanding of what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much.. It did work great but I must have the z values as a data frame not as an XTS.